# Tomcat API unreachable from angular

Tags: typescript, cors, tomcat8

After moving from 'localhost' to online server, I incur in this error
 403 because of CORS.

The api is reachable from url and It works, but when I call it with my
 angular Typescript page, It doesen't work, giving me this error:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 ()
>
> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   '[http://*.*.*.*:8080/bet365/elencoEventi/2019-02-20](http://_._._._:8080/bet365/elencoEventi/2019-02-20)' from origin
>   'http://127.0.0.1:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

I tried to add filters in tomcat, like this :

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

But it is still giving me the 403 error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are on a recent version of Tomcat, you need to configure CORS policies.

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#CORS_Filter

The filter is built into Tomcat 7+

According to the documentation, your configuration enabled the filter but does not relax the cross-origin policy. As a minimum, you will need to add a cors.allowed.origins initialisation parameter as described.

Try this configuration:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter</filter-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>cors.allowed.origins</param-name>
    <param-value>*</param-value>
  </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>CorsFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: I opened the link, but my project is not a meven one, but a Web Application

Comment: I added some additional instructions to the answer

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I solved the problem by adding the dependecies in my tomcat lib repository, following the instruction into the link you post.